# How to render views using Angular + Browserify + Gulp?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

I've been using Angular & Browserify together to create more modular code and use the require syntax on the front-end. I used a gulp task successfully to create my bundle file, but whenever I load my script in my index.html and load up localhost, none of my views render. I've referenced my views in my config file here, which are then loaded into my entry point file that the gulp task uses to compile the bundle file.

However, none of my views render. is there a specific way for doing this?

Ex.

```
function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('Home', {
      url:'/',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'home',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: are you getting any console error?

Comment: no console errors. script loads fine in the browser, none of my views loaded

Comment: have you added `<ui-view></ui-view>` on your page

Comment: i have ui-view added, but the it doesnt reference any other views. ill check to make sure i included ui-router correctly in my angular.module arguments

Comment: ui-router is there..thats why you are not getting any `$moduler` error..could you check you have include `ng-app="appName"` on page..

Comment: yes i have that as well. i actually realized that i am getting a 404 for my views template. i think that in my config file, it references the view relative to the config file, but maybe when the file is compiled into the bundle (which I stick into a folder called public at the root leve that also has my index.html filel) it does not maintain reference to where the view is

Comment: do you suppose i have to use angular $templateCache to avoid the reference mixup?

Comment: you could do that but you need to put your template inside either `script` with `type="text/ng-template"`/ inside `$templateCache` from angular run block

Comment: I see. I guess I didn't take that into consideration, and I assume that's the solution to this.

Comment: frankly speaking I don't understand the term you used "avoid the reference mixup"

Comment: In my configuration file, I have the templateUrl pointing to "views/home.html". I export my config file to app.js, which is the main file I use as the entry point for browserify to build a bundle file. That bundle file is then placed in a folder called "public" at the root level of the project, and contains index.html and the bundled file. However, that bundled js file doesn't have a reference to "views/home.html" as was specified in the config file, so thats what im assuming is the reference mixup. When I load my browser, I get a 404 saying Failed to load http://localhost:3000/views/home.html

Comment: I think it should be `/views/home.html` then

Comment: i had tried that but that didnt solve it either. i guess i just have to process the html to be included into my bundle

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution this is to use $templateCache and cache the html templates. I used a angular-gulp-templatecache to render all of my templates into the angular templates module. Since I'm using browserify, I concatenated my entry point file and my newly created templates file into one file, and then served that from my index.html as main.js.